# Mostrar elementos de una tabla de un componente padre a uno hijo en Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

he creado una tabla en Angular donde estoy haciendo llamado a un arreglo de "Personas", en donde muestro su nombre, apellido y numero de celular que trabaja como componente padre. El problema aparece cuando intento enviar mediante un ***ngFor** los datos de dicha clase a un componente hijo, dándome la estructura de la siguiente forma:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="table-warning">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
          <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
          <th scope="col">Celular</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <app-persona *ngFor="let personaElemento of personas; let i = index"
        [persona] = "personaElemento"
        [indice] = "i">
        </app-persona>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Pero a la hora de revisar en el servidor dicha tabla, se visualiza de la siguiente forma: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado desde el componente hijo adherirme a los elementos de la tabla con el siguiente codigo en .html, pero del mismo resultado, me aparece igual que la imagén mostrada arriba:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{indice+1}}</td>
  <td>{{persona.nombre}}</td>
  <td>{{persona.apellido}}</td>
  <td>{{persona.celular}}</td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT:**
En solicitud de @PabloLozano, adjunto a la pregunta el codigo que aparece en consola del HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el HTML generado por angular?

Comment: @PabloLozano Perdona ¿A que HTML te refieres?, Los 2 códigos de arriba son los 2 componentes de padre-hijo en HTML

Comment: Esas son las plantillas, me refiero al código generado que se ve en el navegador

Comment: @PabloLozano Ahh okey, ahi lo adjunto en la pregunta de arriba

Comment: Creo que sería mejor que el ngFor esté en tu etiqueta `<tr>` y recorres a cada `<td>` con los elementos.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Si, es la forma mas eficiente, pero aplicándolo así el componente hijo quedaría completamente solo, y quisiese ver si existe alguna forma de aplicarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es un problema de estilos: si el display de los elementos no es el correcto, la tabla deja de comportarse como tal:

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$('button').addEventListener('click',() => {
  $('tbody').classList.toggle('inline');
  console.log(getComputedStyle($('tbody')).display);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tbody.inline{
   display: inline;
}

td,th{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="table-warning">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
        <th scope="col">Celular</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <app-persona>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>nombre</td>
          <td>apellido</td>
          <td>celular</td>
        </tr>
      </app-persona>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button>Cambia estilo</button>
```

Comment: Esta fue, muchas gracias!